# How to animate an attached property?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a label in canvas. I want to animate the `Canvas.Left` of the label, but I don't known how to do it...

```
 DoubleAnimation Label_dx = new DoubleAnimation(150,60, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)));

 label.BeginAnimation(???, Label_dx);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
label.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, Label_dx);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use :

```
label.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, Label_dx);
```

or

```
TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
label.RenderTransform = trans;
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(150,60, new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim);
```

The **TranslateTransform** is a specific kind of render transformation. Rather that changing properties of the control (such as the Left property), it simply affects how the control is displayed on the screen